Print multiple correct answers for a question in a single line
I am trying to create a document of MCQ in which there may be more than one options are correct and want to print the answers at the end. If there is only one ans then it works fine however if there are more than one correct choices it does not works as I wanted.
It prints

The goal is to ensure that if there are multiple correct answers for a question, they are listed together in parentheses e.g., 1(a, b) or 2(a,b,c,d).
I dont want to use any other class file as it is part of a larger book style document.
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathpple}
    \usepackage{multicol}


    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \newcounter{choice}
    \renewcommand\thechoice{(\alph{choice})}
    \newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}

    % Define the choices environment with an optional argument for columns
    \makeatletter
    \newenvironment{choices}[1][1]% Default is 1 column if not specified
      {\ifnum#1>1 % Check if the number of columns is more than 1
         \begin{multicols}{#1} % Begin multi-column environment
       \fi
       \list{\choicelabel}%
         {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
           \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0 em}%
           \def\choice{%
             \item
           } % choice
           \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
           \topsep=0pt
           \partopsep=0pt
         }%
      }%
      {\endlist
       \ifnum\col@number>1 % Close multicols if multiple columns were used
         \end{multicols}%
       \fi
      }
    \makeatother

    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \def\CChoice{%
          \choice
          \addanswer{\theenumi}{\thechoice}%
        }
        \let\CChoice\CChoice
        %\par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line
        \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
        \ignorespaces
      {}

    \newbox\allanswers
    \setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}
    \newcommand{\addanswer}[2]{%
      \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~#2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\showanswers}{%
      \vfill
      \begin{center}
        Answers
      \end{center}
      \unhbox\allanswers
    }

    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{document}

    \title{Multiple Choice Questions Example}
    \author{Your Name}
    \date{}
    \maketitle

    \section*{Questions - 1}
    \begin{enumerate}  
      % Question 1 - single column
    \item Which of the following is a square number?
      \begin{choices}
        \choice 5  
        \CChoice 16
        \choice 20
        \choice 23
      \end{choices}
      
      % Question 2 - four columns
    \item Which of the following are elements on the periodic table?
      \begin{choices}[4]
        \CChoice Hydrogen
        \CChoice Helium
        \CChoice Lithium
        \CChoice Carbon
      \end{choices}

      % Question 3 - two columns
    \item Who painted the \textit{Mona Lisa}?
      \begin{choices}[2]
        \CChoice Leonardo da Vinci
        \choice Vincent van Gogh
        \choice Pablo Picasso
        \choice Claude Monet
      \end{choices}
      
      % Question 4 - single column
    \item What is the chemical symbol for Gold?
      \begin{choices}
        \CChoice Au
        \choice Ag
        \choice Pb
        \choice Fe
      \end{choices}
    \end{enumerate}

    %\newpage
    \showanswers
    \end{document}


I removed the tags exam, xparse andxsim because you don't use any of them. Instead I added the tag boxes as you manage answers through the box \allanswers. You should maybe look at the xsim package: it provides many functionalities about printing questions and answers.

What are the purpose of the lines \let\CChoice\CChoice ⏎ \par % Uncomment this to have choices always start a new line ⏎ \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi ⏎  \ignorespaces ⏎ {}? They do nothing.

As I understand \CChoice is used to define the correct answers. But every time it runs the current question number is added.
Redefine \addanswer to accumulate the correct answers of the current question
\newbox\currentanswer
\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{}

\newcommand{\addanswer}[1]{%
  \ifdim \wd\currentanswer > 0pt
    \global\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{\unhbox\currentanswer, #1}
  \else
    \global\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{#1}
  \fi
}

Then \CChoice should only run \addanswer with the answer number, not the question number:
\def\CChoice{%
  \choice
  \addanswer{\alph{choice}}%
}

At the end of the choices environment, add
\storeanswer{\theenumi}%

where \storeanswer is your previous macro \addanswer, adapted to use the content in \currentanswer
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}

\newcommand{\storeanswer}[1]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~(\unhbox\currentanswer)}%
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathpple}
\usepackage{multicol}


% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{(\alph{choice})}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice}

% Define the choices environment with an optional argument for columns
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{choices}[1][1]% Default is 1 column if not specified
{\ifnum#1>1 % Check if the number of columns is more than 1
    \begin{multicols}{#1} % Begin multi-column environment
    \fi
    \list{\choicelabel}%
    {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
      \settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0 em}%
      \def\choice{%
      \item
      } % choice
      \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
      \topsep=0pt
      \partopsep=0pt
    }%
  }%
  {\endlist
    \ifnum\col@number>1 % Close multicols if multiple columns were used
    \end{multicols}%
  \fi%
  \storeanswer{\theenumi}%
}
\makeatother

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\CChoice{%
  \choice
  \addanswer{\alph{choice}}%
}

\newbox\currentanswer
\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{}

\newcommand{\addanswer}[1]{%
  \ifdim \wd\currentanswer > 0pt
    \global\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{\unhbox\currentanswer, #1}
  \else
    \global\setbox\currentanswer=\hbox{#1}
  \fi
}

\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{}

\newcommand{\storeanswer}[1]{%
  \global\setbox\allanswers=\hbox{\unhbox\allanswers \quad #1.~(\unhbox\currentanswer)}%
}

\newcommand{\showanswers}{%
  \vfill
  \begin{center}
    Answers
  \end{center}
  \unhbox\allanswers
}

% --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\title{Multiple Choice Questions Example}
\author{Your Name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section*{Questions - 1}
\begin{enumerate}
  % Question 1 - single column
\item Which of the following is a square number?
  \begin{choices}
    \choice 5
    \CChoice 16
    \choice 20
    \choice 23
  \end{choices}

  % Question 2 - four columns
\item Which of the following are elements on the periodic table?
  \begin{choices}[4]
    \CChoice Hydrogen
    \CChoice Helium
    \CChoice Lithium
    \CChoice Carbon
  \end{choices}

  % Question 3 - two columns
\item Who painted the \textit{Mona Lisa}?
  \begin{choices}[2]
    \CChoice Leonardo da Vinci
    \choice Vincent van Gogh
    \choice Pablo Picasso
    \choice Claude Monet
  \end{choices}

  % Question 4 - single column
\item What is the chemical symbol for Gold?
  \begin{choices}
    \CChoice Au
    \choice Ag
    \choice Pb
    \choice Fe
  \end{choices}
\end{enumerate}

% \newpage
\showanswers
\end{document}



Thank you so much, I was stuck at this for a very long time. If you dont mind is there that I type Questions for section 1 and Questions for section 2 etc and after that I am able to print the answers of section 1, section 2 and so on...

@Kumarm I'm not sure to fully understand your question, but as implemented \showanswers clears the box \allanswers, so if you use \showasnwer at the end of each section you can show the answers, section by section. For a more general approch, see, for example, the xsim package.
